# $N(T^n) = N(T^{n+1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map and $\dim(V ) < \infty$.

How can I show that there is an $n > 0$ such that $N(T^n) = N(T^{n+1})$?

Could someone here possibly help?

Comment: $dim(V) < 1$? Shouldn't it be $> 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $N(T) \subset N(T^2) \subset \dots \subset N(T^n) \subset N(T^{n+1}) \subset \dots \subset V$ and that the sequence of nonnegative integers $(\dim(N(T^n)))$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: I think non-increasing should be non-decreasing.

Comment: Thank you, I eddited my answer.